# Getting a number from a string

Tags: string, actionscript-3

I have a string with a number on the end, `"slot1"` and would like to get the number from it.

```
currentSlot.name = "slot1";
slotNumber =  currentSlot.name - "slot"; // I want it to be 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want a `number` then you probably need to convert it.

you will need `substr()` to get the number and `Number()` to convert it to number.

You can convert strings that are made up of numerical characters into actual Number data using the `Number()`

```
currentSlot.name = "slot1";
slotNumber =  Number(currentSlot.name.substr(4));
```

`Number()` constructor expects a number, so don't put a calculation inside

Comment: Given that OP has a static first part of string, it'll be better to produce a substring based on its length, `currentSlot.name.substr(4)`, otherwise if he'd try parsing `slot12` your code will return only `2` instead of `12`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar needs in previous projects and decided to use RegExp, so, doesn't matter the string format, always will extract the number (if possible).

```
var n:Number = getNumbersFromString("slot1"); // can be 1slot, s1lot, etc) always will return 1

trace(n, n is Number);

function getNumbersFromString(source:String):Number
{
    var pattern:RegExp = /[^0-9]/g;
    return Number(source.replace(pattern, ''));
}
```

Comment: `slot1part2` - just in case. Regexps are nice, but this might be killing a sparrow with a nuclear warhead.

Comment: @Vesper, I totally agree, maybe for this case is not necessary, because the format of the string is follow a pattern, but I thought that was a good idea to show some generic variant as well